# Is there a way of setting the size of an arraylist after declaring it?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For example, in a traditional array, i would declare an array like this:

```
int array[];
```

then, i would later initialize it like this

```
array = new int[1000];
```

in an arraylist i am trying to do the same but I have only been able to initialize it while declaring it like below.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>(1000);
```

it's almost the same as

```
int[] array = new int[10000];
```

So I would like to know if there's a way to initialize an arraylist to for example 1000 after it's been declared in a separate statement.

Comment: why would you want to delcare the size of the arraylist for?

Comment: ArrayList javadoc, go

Comment: I'm writing a program where the users enters the array list initial capacity and that will be the array's size.

Comment: You're confusing size with initial capacity.  Except for perf, there is no reason to do this.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi With the given code, `arrayList.get(1)` will result in an exception while `array[1]` won't .. *why?* (That's the secret to this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ensureCapacity(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29)

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();

al.ensureCapacity(1000);
```

It is important to note that array lists WILL dynamically resize themselves though.

> So I would like to know if there's a way to initialize an arraylist to for example 1000 after it's been declared in a separate statement.

You could always do this, too:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al;

al = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);
```

This is more akin to the regular array initialisation.

Comment: That may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: After seeing your edit, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is not same as declaring size for array, it is initial size you are passing in

you can still go beyond `1000` runtime in case of `List` and not in array

`ArrayList` dynamically will grow the size as required, 1000 here is initial size of array wrapped under `ArrayList`

Comment: I've read somewhere that if an array list has an initial capacity, it will be more optimized than if it doesn't

Comment: You read it right, if you know you need 100 elements you should tell it at declaration time it will reserve array with the size of 100 internally, if you don't tell it it will reserve array of size 10 by default and as you keep adding it will have to perform allocation and moving of data 10 times which is slower

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to do this besides performance reasons, but you can use the [`ensureCapacity` method.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29)

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(100);
//code, code, code, ask user size of ArrayList
array.ensureCapacity(someUserInputSize);
```

Comment: You have already ensured a capacity of `100` with the constructor argument.

Comment: `ensureCapacity` will allow you to ensure a capacity larger than `100` if need be.  You could put the call to `ensureCapacity` within an `if` statement if you really wanted to, but if you call `ensureCapacity(50)` on an `ArrayList` that already has ensured capacity of more than 50, it doesn't do anything.  If you call `ensureCapacity(200)` on an `ArrayList` that doesn't have this capacity ensured, you'll ensure it.

Comment: That's correct but doesn't really answer the (admittedly confusing) question.

Comment: How doesn't it?  He wants to assure that his `ArrayList` will have a certain capacity before he starts putting stuff into his `ArrayList`.  If he doesn't, then when he passes the `ArrayList`'s current capacity, he takes a performance hit as the `ArrayList` has to copy all of its current contents into a new block of memory that will allow for this higher capacity.  Using `ensureCapacity` before putting anything into the `ArrayList` improves performance by ensuring your `ArrayList` is in a block of memory large enough before it has to copy a lot of contents.

Comment: Yes, I understand all that but I think we read the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if there's a way to initialize an arraylist to for example 1000 after it's been declared in a separate statement.

You can declare it first, then initialize it later, just like with the array:

```
ArrayList<String> array;

...

array = new ArrayList<>(1000);
```

But just so you know, the argument of this [`ArrayList(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) constructor is the *initial capacity* of the backing array, rather than the size - it's merely an optimization one can do if the expected size of the `ArrayList` is known. An `ArrayList` instantiated this way will still be *empty* until elements are added.